# Updating a pandas dataframe or csv with dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

A function in my script returns a dictionary for `John` as follows:

```
{ "Apple": 10, "Mango": 20, "Banana":30}
```

The keys and values are not necessarily the same every time I call the function. For example, it can also yield a dictionary for `Jen` such as

```
{ "Apple": 10, "Banana":30, "Watermelon": 5}
```

I want to update the values to preferably a csv (or to a pandas dataframe and then to csv) to store it for later analysis.
 The desired output of the csv is:

```
Name | Apple | Banana | Mango | Watermelon |
------------------------------------------
John | 10    | 30     | 20    |            
Jen  | 10    | 30     |       | 5
```

So, the puedocode is as follows:

```
if dictionary-keys == csv_or_df_header:
   add value to corresponding columns by matching keys with column headers
else:
   add the new key as a column header
   add value to corresponding columns by matching keys with column headers
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pandas [append](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) function takes care of most of this work for you. This code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Apple': 10, "Mango": 20, "Banana": 30}, index=['John'])

jen = pd.Series({"Apple": 10, "Banana": 30, "Watermelon": 5}, name='Jen')
df = df.append(jen)

print(df)
```

yields this result:

```
      Apple  Banana  Mango  Watermelon
John   10.0    30.0   20.0         NaN
Jen    10.0    30.0    NaN         5.0
```

If you want to move it [to csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) from there you can tack `df.to_csv(csv_filepath)` on the end of the program and it'll export it to the filepath you specified.

Comment: Nice. That is a cool way to do it. However, can we have multiple values in the ```pd.Series({"Apple": 10, "Banana": 30, "Watermelon": 5}, name='Jen', gender='female', place='something')```. When I tried to do the same, I get keyword unknown error.

Comment: `name` is an attribute of [Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) and is therefor put in it's constructor. It's a coincidence that, in this case, we are actually trying to pass a person's name.

Comment: Also, as a side note, you can save some space, but reduce readability to some degree by instantiating the Series in the append statement like: `df = df.append(pd.Series({"Apple": 10, "Banana": 30, "Watermelon": 5}, name='Jen'))`

Answer (score 3):

So, if your data looks like this:

```
data = {'John': { "Apple": 10, "Mango": 20, "Banana":30},
        'Jen': { "Apple": 10, "Banana":30, "Watermelon": 5}}
```

You can create `dataframe` from it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```

And to update it, you can revert to dict:

```
df = df.to_dict(orient='index')
```

Update the dict:

```
update = {'Jack': { "Apple": 10, "Mango": 20, "Kiwi":60}}
df.update(update)
```

And push it back to `dataframe`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient='index')
```

Furthermore, if you want to replace `NaN` just use `fillna()` at the end:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient='index').fillna('').astype(int,raise_on_error=False)
```

Result:

```
     Mango Watermelon  Apple Banana Kiwi
Jack    20                10          60
Jen                 5     10     30     
John    20                10     30
```

Comment: Any performance advantages of using ```df.update``` over ```df.append``` (as per @eric-ed-lohmar 's answer)?

Comment: Well `append` is for `dataframe` object, and `update` is for `dict` that I used as a middleman. You can `%timeit` to see which one is faster, but output should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dictionary operation [`get(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get),

```
# Let's say you return  a name and a dict from your scirpt
name = 'John'
d = { "Apple": 10, "Mango": 20, "Banana":30}

# Add the record to a list of lists
lists = list()
lists.append([name, d.get('Apple', ''), d.get('Banana', ''), d.get('Mango', ''), d.get('Watermelon', '')])

# Write to a csv file
fieldnames = ['Name', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Watermelon']
with open('result.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames) # write the header 
    writer.writerows(lists)     # write a list of lists
```